# Excel Array, Ignore if left adjacent cell is blank

Tags: arrays, excel, min

I have an array formula in column "H", of sheet "Parts Inventory", that works until the reference cells are blank.

```
=MIN(IF(tbl_PurchaseOrderTracking[Manufacturer Part Number]=B4,IF(tbl_PurchaseOrderTracking[Unit Cost]<>"",tbl_PurchaseOrderTracking[Unit Cost])))
```

I need it to ignore if B4 is blank on sheet "Parts Inventory".

[image]

Comment: If with "it doesn't work" you mean it returns an error, you might try adding an [IFERROR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) function.

Comment: It's not returning errors. It pulls in the lowest dollar value of referenced values with no [Manufacturer Part Number] value (blank cells).

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest wrapping your Array formula in an `IF` condition will help get around it like below.

`=IF(B4<>"",MIN(IF(tbl_PurchaseOrderTracking[Manufacturer Part Number]=B4,IF(tbl_PurchaseOrderTracking[Unit Cost]<>"",tbl_PurchaseOrderTracking[Unit Cost]))),"")`